# undefined method `def_delegator' for Datatable:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have build a datatable and try to use link_to and _path helper within my datatable.rb. I get an "undefined method" error, when using def_delegator. According to this [link](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/21) it should work. Why am i not able to use def_delegator ?

datatable.rb:

```
class NetworkDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord


  def_delegator :@view, :link_to
  def_delegator :@view, :network_path


  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
       network: { source: "Network.network"},
       comment: { source: "Network.comment"}
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {  
         network: link_to(record.id, "#", network_path(record.id), :onclick => "display_dialog(); return(false);"),
         comment: record.comment
      }
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
     Network.all
  end

end
```

error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `def_delegator' for NetworkDatatable:Class):

app/datatables/network_datatable.rb:4:in `<class:NetworkDatatable>'
app/datatables/network_datatable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4):

`def_delegator` is a method on [Forwardable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) class

In order to use it you will have to do the following:

```
require 'forwardable'

class NetworkDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :@view, :link_to

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try the following instead

```
class NetworkDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord
  delegate :link_to, :network_path, to: :@view
end
```

`def_delegator` is a [`Forwardable`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) method and I do not see the extension of this module. Although you could obviously extend your class with this module as others have proposed.

However [`Module#delegate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) is a method rails has added to the `Module` class (meaning it is accessible in almost every class) and should work consistently with the proposed.

Please note the method signatures differ slightly.

`Forwardable#def_delegator` (ruby standard lib)

```
# def_delegator :target, :method
```

`Forwardable#def_delegators` plural (ruby standard lib)

```
# def_delegators :target, :method1, :method2, ..., :method_n
```

`Module#delegate` (rails only)

```
# delegate :method1, :method2, ..., :method_n, to: :target
```

Answer (score 1):

The `def_forwardable` method is defined in Ruby's standard library [`Forwardable`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module, so the class needs to extend the module to be able to use it. There is an example of this method in the section [Using View Helpers](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails#using-view-helpers) of the ajax-datatables-rails project.

```
require 'forwardable'

class NetworkDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :@view, :link_to
  def_delegator :@view, :network_path

end
```

Comment: You have typo in extend there ;]